# Transfer of variables between seperate windows in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Im quite new to Wpf and i have a LoginWindow and MainWindow, i've defined a variable named "currentUser" that stores the name of the currently logged in user after reading from a database. However i want to access this info in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file and then use the name as content for a Label in the MainWindow.

So the question is, is there any easy way to transfer a variables info from one window to another without having to store and reread the database ?

Already tried reading another post saying to make it static or public. Neither worked? And someone said something about databinding but im still not 100% on that process.

Comment: Using a separate class to hold that information is best. Think of it as a program state. Once you have a user logged in, you store that information in something like `AccountStore` and pass the instance of `AccountStore` to any viewmodels that require access to its information.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example store the values in a static field:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    public static string currentUser;
}
```

**LoginWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
ApplicationService.currentUser = "some user...";
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
string currentUser = ApplicationService.currentUser;
```